# PHP Warning: ftp_get() [function.ftp-get]: 2.262 seconds (measured here), 1.15 Mbytes per second

Tags: php, ftp, get, warnings

I created an import script that imports a file. After several minutes, and each time, I get this warning:

> Warning:  ftp_get() [function.ftp-get]: 2.262 seconds (measured here),
>   1.15 Mbytes per second

All files produce the same warning.  I am running this script on the serverside.  Is there anyone who has had this error?  Here is the line of code that produces the warning.

```
ftp_get($conn_id,'data/'.$newFileName, $file, FTP_BINARY);
```

Same warning occurs when I use FTP_ASCII instead of FTP_BINARY

```
My Server:   Linux
PHP version: 5.2.6-1+lenny9 
Apache:      Apache 2.0 Handler
```

My htaccess:

```
php_value post_max_size 55M
php_value upload_max_filesize 54M
php_value memory_limit 55M
```

What does that warning mean?

Comment: Here a user has reported the same warning message for ftp_delete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318947/php-warning-ftp-delete-20130113070104

Comment: The fourth parameter of ftp_get is the mode.  Do you get the same warning if you use `FTP_ASCII` instead of `FTP_BINARY`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php

Comment: Same things, on the same file!

Comment: Do you get the same warning if you turn passive mode on like this: `ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);`  Put that line before your ftp_get line.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php

Comment: Other people have reported this problem with WAMP, are you using WAMP?

Comment: I put it before my recursive function. A lot of files download well before the cursor arrive to "the" file, and I have the error, and the same error for all other files after.

Comment: This is an elusive bug that the developers have wanted to squish for a long time but have trouble reproducing the error consistently as you have.  This is a rare opportunity to explore it.  What operating system are you using and What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Server : Linux 

PHP : PHP Version 5.2.6-1+lenny9

Apache : Apache 2.0 Handler

Comment: Can you use ftp from the terminal to get a file, and does the same warning happen?  This would tell us if PHP ftp_get(...) is failing, or your ftp server is failing and or mis configured or blocked by something.  http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/FTP-3.html  Another strategy would be to download FileZilla, and use the GUI to use the ftp option to connect, and see if it returns the same warning.

Comment: With FileZilla, I can download the warning's files and it works fine.

Comment: I think that error is generated by your FTP server. what is your FTP server?

Comment: This is a client server. How can I have the informations you need?